# QT add Label to certain position

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I'm new to QT and I want to know how to add a label on a certain position by code. I create a new application and I have these code automatically:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I want to add a label to a certain position, for example, its geometry is (10, 10, 30, 80). How do I do this by code? Someone can help me?

Comment: You should checkout the Qt tutorials. They help you a lot there.

Comment: 1) Use Qt Designer. 2) Create an instance of `QLabel` manually. What is your exact problem? Did you try to read Qt tutorials?

Comment: See also here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info

Comment: create a QLabel object and set its parent you main window then use qlabel->setGeometry(QRectF(10,10,30,80))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an instance of [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html), like this: (Here is the example from the docs. Try implementing it yourself with your standards. The docs are helpful)

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
label->setText("first line\nsecond line");
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
//Here is how to change position:
label->setGeometry(QRectF(10,10,30,80));
```

By the way, here is what an example `QLabel` looks like:

[image: Text Label]

Comment: It work's! By the way, what are the docs? A link will be helpful^_^

Comment: Why I fail to create this label when I put these code in the on_button_clicked() function?

Comment: See http://www.qtforum.org/article/31684/set-the-text-of-a-label-using-a-pushbutton.html?s=03e451860f88b3f356539ee5e95a873138fd1c5d#post111464